# Размер логотипа ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

При конвертации вместе в размером видео увеличивается и логотип. Пытался указать непосредственно размер лого, но все бесполезно. Аспект видео конвертируется с 4:3 на 16:9 и логотип тоже изменяется. Вот код:

```
/usr/bin/avconv -i  "vob.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -sn -vf "movie=hd.png [watermark]; [in]yadif,hqdn3d=2:1:2,setsar=1:1,setdar=16:9 [scale]; [scale][watermark] overlay=20:20 [out]" -crf 20.0 -s hd720 -pix_fmt yuv444p -sar 1:1 -aspect 16:9 -f matroska -preset slow -tune film -sws_flags lanczos -acodec libfdk_aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -b:a 448k -coder 1 -flags +loop -cmp chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method hex -subq 6 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -b_strategy 1 -threads 0 -b:v 1800k  -maxrate 1900k -bufsize 3000k -r 25 -f null -an -passlogfile "/tmp/film.log" -pass 1  -y /dev/null && /usr/bin/avconv -y -i "vob.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -sn -vf "movie=hd.png [watermark]; [in]yadif,hqdn3d=2:1:2,setsar=1:1,setdar=16:9 [scale]; [scale][watermark] overlay=20:20 [out]" -crf 20.0 -s hd720 -pix_fmt yuv444p -sar 1:1 -aspect 16:9 -f matroska -preset slow -tune film -sws_flags lanczos -s hd720 -acodec libfdk_aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -b:a 448k -coder 1 -flags +loop -cmp chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method hex -subq 6 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -b_strategy 1 -threads 0 -b:v 1800k  -maxrate 1900k -bufsize 3000k -r 25 -passlogfile "/tmp/film.log" -pass 2  "out.mkv"
```

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1):

Не мешать фильтры и задание размера и аспекта через опции (-s, -aspect, -sar). Скалируйте тоже фильтром: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1

А тут ещё примерчики: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался :)

Comment: @varnava за это можно отметить ответ решением ;-)